# Erro na hora de passar o resultado de um array json para o html;

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou com a seguinte situação, tenho uma página que recebe o nome de uma cidade, entre São Paulo ou Osasco, tanto a requisição da ida via Ajax, quanto o dado em json está voltando do php para o Js, porém eu tenho uma outra página chamada cards.php que deveria mostrar os dados da previsão do tempo em 7 cards. porém na hora que eu clico no botão submit, não muda de tela, e na cards.php  não muda os valores. Coloquei os cards no index para ver, ele recebe um dos valores, mas some muito rápido, na hora que ele recebe passa 2 segundos já some e fica vazio. No console, tem hora que aparece um erro, mas também aparece rápido demais e não dá para ver o erro.

Projeto no Github
https://github.com/Marcos-Vinicius1801/Challenge

index.

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#enviar").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  });

$("#enviar").click(function(){
    var city = $('#city').val();

    $.post("http://localhost:5000/cidade.action.php",
        {city: city}, function(data){
              for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
                // alert(data[i].probability);
                if(data[i].probability)
                {
                    $('#data'+i).html(data[i].probability);
                    break;
                }
            }
    },'json').fail(function(){
        alert("Cidade não encontrada!");
    });
  });
})
```

cards.php

```
  <section class="cards container animar_interno">
     <h2 class="subtitulo"></h2>
     <ul class="cards_lista">
        <li class="grid-1-3">
           <div class="cards_icone">
           </div>
           <h3 id="data1"></h3>
           <p id="texto1"></p>
           <p id="maxima1"><img src="img/upload.png" alt="Máxima"></p>
           <p id="minima1"><img src="img/low.png" alt="Minima"></p>
           <p id="precipitacao-chuva1"><img src="img/raindrop-close-up.png" alt="Preciptação de chuva"></p>
           <p id="possibilidade-chuva1"><img src="img/protection-symbol-of-opened-umbrella-silhouette-under-raindrops.png" alt="Chance de chover"></p>
        </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o erro, eu estava usando **dois eventos** com o mesmo id, dai um anulava o outro, depois de ter colocado a requisição ajax embaixo do **e.preventDefault();** funcionou perfeitamente.